# Recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, recursion

The program has two functions `human_pyramid(no_of_people)` that will take no_of_people in the base as argument and will return the weight of the total pyramid

```
    x
  x x x
X X X X X <=== this is the argument (no_of_people = 5)
```

the weight of each person is taken 50 and the function will return 450

```
def human_pyramid(no_of_people):
    if no_of_people == 1:
        return 50
    else:
        return no_of_people*(50)+human_pyramid(no_of_people-2)
```

The second fucntion takes max_weight as an argument and returns the number of people that can form the human pyramid without exceeding max weight.

```
def find_maximum_people(max_weight):
    no_of_people=0
    while human_tower(no_of_people) <= max_weight:
        no_of_people +=1
    return no_of_people

max_people=find_maximum_people(1000)
print(max_people)
```

I'm getting an RecursionError on the line `while human_tower(no_of_people) <= max_weight:` and
 `return no_of_people*(50)+human_pyramid(no_of_people-2)`
but running the `function human_pyramid(no_of_people)` on its own it runs fine

Comment: I assume you know what recursion is yes? If so what's happening is that your recursion is stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: the above code with work only if the `no_of_people` originally passed is an odd number. If it happens to be an even number, then the condition `if no_of_people == 1` will never be true and recursion will not terminate.

Comment: @Kwright02. Not necessarily (but true in this case). It could just mean a small stack.

Comment: That's true too @MadPhysicist

Comment: @OP, Have you tried debugging this in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if no_of_people == 1:
    return 50
else :
    return no_of_people*(50)+human_pyramid(no_of_people-2)
```

the condition `no_of_people == 1` will become True only if the value originally passed is odd.

As a solution you may add one more base case for when no_of_people == 0

```
if no_of_people == 1:
    return 50
elif no_of_people == 0:
    return 0
else :
    return no_of_people*(50)+human_pyramid(no_of_people-2)
```